# How to Stop notification popping up in android

Tags: android, notifications

When I open my android application it will popup notification. i want to disable it.

My online audio streaming  android app. Popping notification when android app is open.  I need to build notification without popping up.

Also Please note that i have try below answer and it not working for me.
[Create notification without it popping up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112719/create-notification-without-it-popping-up)

```
      if (i >= 26) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(str,
                    "Foreground Service Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(false);
            notificationChannel.setSound(null, null);
            Objects.requireNonNull(getSystemService(NotificationManager.class))
                    .createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        }
        Intent closeButton = new Intent("Notification_Button");
        PendingIntent pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, closeButton, 0);
        Bitmap notifyIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.official_logo_app);

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgBtnPlay, pendingSwitchIntent);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, str);

        builder.setLargeIcon(notifyIcon)
                .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                        new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0))
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_SECRET)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{0})
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContent(remoteViews)
                .setTicker(null)
        ;
        startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

Comment: try with setTicker(null)

Comment: hi @Ankit i have try setTicker(null), but still notification popping up

Comment: Not sure it will fix your problem, but `NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL` is not a valid value to pass to `setPriority`  You want one of the `NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_*` values, probably `NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT`